# CURL error: [77] error setting certificate verify locations: using LetsEncrypt certificate

Tags: php, ssl, curl, apache2

I know this question has been asked in multiple threads and for many situations.  I have been searching through these threads for days now.  I'm still at a loss.  I'm hoping someone here can shed some new light.

I think the question is:  What do I need to do to get PHP CURL to use the certificate issued to the web site.  In this case, the LetsEncrypt certificate is issued by using CERTBOT.  The certificate is valid according to the browsers I have tested with.

My domain is: app.ccgopvt.org

I ran this PHP procedure...

```
    $sslCertPath = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/app.ccgopvt.org/fullchain.pem";
    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    // Assign CAINFO to the specific SSL Cert ONLY IF it is self-authorized.
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $sslCertPath);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if ( ! ($response)) {
        $errno = curl_errno($ch);
        $errstr = curl_error($ch);
        $response = "postToURL - CURL error: [$errno] $errstr.";
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    It produced this output:
    postToURL - CURL error: [77] error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.ccgopvt.org/fullchain.pem CApath: /etc/ssl/certs.
```

My web server is (include version):
Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
Server built: 2019-10-13T15:43:54

The operating system my web server runs on is (include version):
Debian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l

My hosting provider, if applicable, is: myself

I can login to a root shell on my machine (yes or no, or I don't know): yes

I'm using a control panel to manage my site (no, or provide the name and version of the control panel): no

The version of my client is (e.g. output of `certbot --version` or `certbot-auto --version` if you're using Certbot):
certbot 0.28.0

I can run curl directly from the command line for the same URL and I get a valid response. e.g...

```
    # curl https://app.ccgopvt.org
    
    
      
</head>
<body>
<h1>You have reached the CCGOPVT Admin Pages</h1>
...
```

This behavior is specific to my web applications. Things were working, and suddenly they weren't. (Yes, of course something changed. I'm just at a loss for what!) The initial setting of $sslCertPath above was NULL. (That's my default setting on other servers.) But that produced the error. The above tries to assign the LetsEncrypt certificate path, but the result is the same.

I'm sure I am missing something basic in my understanding of how CURL uses SSL certificates. Somehow, I think this problem has to do with the interaction of the two. I'm hoping someone here can help.

Thanks in advance,

Ron

Comment: One more bit of information:

The following setting for CAINFO seems to work!


    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/etc/apache2/ssl/cacert.pem" );


Setting CAINFO to the LetsEncrypt certificate does not...


    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/etc/letsencrypt/live/app.ccgopvt.org/fullchain.pem" );

This latter setting results in the CURL error.